# How to draw a rounded transparent rectangle over GLKView

Tags: ios, avcapturesession

I'm working on a business card scanner application and I'm using AVCaptureSession and AVCaptureDevice for detecting edges of the card. I'd like to create a view on top of the preview layer which is rendered using GLKView and that view should have rounded rectangles and the outside of the rectangle should be blurred and the inside should be transparent.

Like this image:
[image: Like this image.]

How can I achieve this in Objective-C?

Thanks
Jugs

Answer (score 0):

You can set background color of view to the UIColor with alpha

```
coverView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5];
```